# How to insert row id to another table field using php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have first table name is **conference**.

[image: click this image]

I want to insert table conference row id (81) to another second table name **conf_dates**

and that have field **conf_id** use for save conference row id

[image: click this image]

The issue is that value is empty insert in second table **conf_dates** as shown in second table image

**Here is php code**

```
<?php

    $id = $_GET["id"];

    $trans = array("strtdate"=>$strtdate,"enddate"=>$enddate,"conf_id"=>$id);

    $query = $db->insert($trans,PREFIX."conf_dates");

    ?>
```

**Here is html code**

```
 <p>
    <label>Conference ID</label>

    <input name="conf_id" class="text-input medium-input" type="text" id="conf_id" value="" /> 
</p>
```

Please tell me how to insert row id to another table field?

Comment: Do a `print_r($trans);` and tell us what you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what are the values of $strtdate, $enddate
Also please share the table structure of  `"conf_dates"` .

```
$id =  intval($_GET["id"]);
```

check you are getting correct types, and values for variables you trying to insert

Answer (score 0):

You named the input field `conf_id` while you try to insert `$_GET['id']`.
You should insert $_GET['conf_id']` instead.